# android getting dimension of extended view in main activity

Tags: android, view, dimension

Maybe this is a simple question...
I am now working on a drawing app of which the main activity (A) is extending a View named DoodleView.

I know how to measure the dimension in DoodleView simply by `onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH)`, but I would like to know how to measure the dimension of the DoodleView in A. I have researched some of the other similar questions but seem most of them are asking how to get dimension inside the extended View.

I have tried the following in A's `OnCreate`:

```
  private DoodleView doodleView;
  doodleView = (DoodleView) findViewById(R.id.doodleView);

  doodleViewWidth = doodleView.getMeasuredWidth(); 
  doodleViewHeight = doodleView.getMeasuredHeight(); 

  Toast.makeText(Doodlz.this, "W=" + doodleViewWidth + "H= "+doodleViewHeight, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And the toast reports 0 for both W and H.

Is it possible to get dimension of the extended view in Main Activity A? I would like to ask this because there are some more `GetActivityResult` in this main activity that need to manipulate the importing picture according to the DoodleView dimension.

Many thanks!

Comment: in OnCreate() doodleView is not measured yet. Have You tried to use ViewTreeObserver to know the moment doodleView get drawn (at that moment it should be measured already).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
doodleView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        doodleViewWidth = doodleView.getWidth(); 
        doodleViewHeight = doodleView.getHeight();
        // here goes your code...
    }
});
```

EDIT:
Please note that the two variables can't be accessed before the onGlobalLayout() hasn't been called at least once (or they will be just 0). Depending on what and when you need the values for your code will look differently.
You could just put the code that uses the values in the onGlobalLayout() method or you could send a message using a Handler and the do you processing in the Handler's handleMessage().

Comment: I have tried but it still returns null...=( do you have any hints?